# CSS Whitespace Normal not wrapping on h3 tag

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get some text to wrap so I have this:

```
h3.h3_title {
    white-space:normal !important;
}
```

Here is the html:

```
<li>
<a href="#">
<img src="img.png" />
<h3 class="h3_title">this is some text which is supposed to wrap but it is not happening</h3>
</a>
</li>
```

For some reason it's not wrapping..and ideas why?

Comment: Did you try in another browser?

Comment: It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/RqEDe/ So what you've provided does not include the actual problem.

Comment: Sorry about the \ ... wasn't supposed to be there :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
h3.h3_title {
    white-space:normal !important;
    width:20px !important;
}
```

Set width according to your conditon